# Can't connect dumped MongoDB with Rails 3.1 and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongoimport

A Rails 3.1 app is running locally fine with MongoDB and mongoid (until I don't modify anything).

I need the production DB so I dumped it properly. Now **I need to configure the Rails app to connect or use this new dumped database**.

I copied all the Mongodb's BSON files into the folder where my local Mongo (which started by 'mongod' command) looking for **(/data). All files in one folder (/data/e)**.

**How to configure MongoDB or Rails or mongoid.yml to use specifically that folder which I moved there?**

+++

Additional info:
Made mongodump successfully. Now I need to import it to the testserver, probably with mongoimport. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't do that. To dump/restore a MongoDB database, you should use the [mongodump and mongorestore utilities](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Import+Export+Tools?focusedCommentId=5799964#comment-5799964)